# How to check if Kafka is up only using the commandline?

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose

I wanted my shell script for integration tests to wait until Kafka is up. I tried this command to fetch topics from Kafka, but it reported even before Docker compose showed `[KafkaServer id=1001] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)`. Maybe it was reading from Zookeeper instead of Kafka.

```
docker start queue-service-kafka && docker-compose exec kafka /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper=zookeeper:2181
```

So is there a way to wait until it comes up? I hate the alternative of `sleep <x seconds>`.

Comment: Integration tests using Java? Or even without Java, could the shell scripts be converted? https://www.testcontainers.org/usage/kafka_containers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a little trick I use for Kafka Connect, that you could apply to Kafka brokers too with appropriate modification of the log string expected:

```
export CONNECT_HOST=kafka-connect-cp
echo -e "\n--\n\nWaiting for Kafka Connect to start on $CONNECT_HOST … ⏳"
grep -q "Kafka Connect started" <(docker-compose logs -f $CONNECT_HOST)
echo "Now do something that needs to wait for Kafka Connect
```

The magic is in line three, which `grep`s the output of the log from Docker Compose and waits for the supplied text before continuing execution.

---

Your `kafka-topics` returns too soon *I think* because it's only going to ZK, not Kafka. You could try `kafkacat` instead for interrogating the broker itself.

You could also try `nc -vz broker-host 9092` and wait for it to be available, but that's not always a guarantee the broker's actually *ready*.

Comment: Thanks. My relevant string is `INFO [KafkaServer id=1001] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)`. I explored techniques at https://superuser.com/questions/270529/monitoring-a-file-until-a-string-is-found

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend using an additional docker container for your purposes:

```
# Will shutdown automatically
init-kafka:
  image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
  depends_on:
    - base_your_kafka_container
  entrypoint: [ '/bin/sh', '-c' ]
  command: |
    "
     echo -e 'Blocks until kafka is reachable'
     opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --list
    "
```